# Conflicting cointegration results due to different lags in Johansen procedure

Tags: time-series, cointegration, lags, ardl

I have been using two different models for cointegration: Johansen's test and ARDL (autoregressive distributed lag). I guess this example could be extendent for other cointegration models as well.

I have a sample of 46 annual data points. For the ARDL model, cointegration is found with lag 2 of the variables (found by Schwarz (SIC) criterion), i.e. in total 44 observations are used.

For Johansen's test the lag due to SIC criterion is 1 (45 observations are used) and no cointegration vector is found. However, if I increase the max lag to 2 (44 observations are used), one cointegration vector does exist.

**Questions:**

1. Should I trust the SIC criterion in this case?
2. If one wants to compare the models, should one use the same lag length in order to use the same number of observations?